# Несколько элементов с одинаковым селектором

Tags: javascript, material-design

В распоряжении имеем две кнопки с одинаковым селектором `data-show-dialog`. Первая найденная кнопка при клике открывает модальное окно, а вторая - не работает. Как заставить работать обе кнопки с вышеупомянутыми одинаковыми селекторами?

```js
var dialog = document.querySelector('#dialog-contact');
var showDialogButton = document.querySelector('[data-show-dialog]');

if (!dialog.showModal) {
  dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
}

showDialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  dialog.showModal();
});

dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
  dialog.close();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<button data-show-dialog class="mdl-button mdl-js-button">
  Обратиться
</button>

<button data-show-dialog class="mdl-button mdl-js-button ">
  Задать вопрос
</button>

<dialog class="mdl-dialog" id="dialog-contact">
  <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
  Отправить
</button>
<button type="button" class="mdl-button mdl-js-ripple-effect close">
  Закрыть
</button>
  </div>
</dialog>
```

Comment: `querySelector` возвращает первый подходящий элемент, чтобы получить все нужно использовать `querySelectorAll`, и обходить полученную коллекцию в цикле

Comment: @Grundy сработало, благодарю.

Comment: вообще все это как-то противоестественно, есть же `id`, его и используйте, или объемлете кнопки в один див, и там слушайте события, а на обработчике, дифференцируйте по тому же `id`

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в том, что [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) возвращает *первый* подходящий элемент. Для того, чтобы вернуть *все*, необходимо использовать [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), либо аналогичную функцию возвращающую коллекцию, и добавлять обработчик проходя по элементам коллекции в цикле.

Например:

```
var showDialogButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-show-dialog]');
[...showDialogButtons].forEach(showDialogButton =>
  showDialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    dialog.showModal();
  }));
```

```js
var dialog = document.querySelector('#dialog-contact');
var showDialogButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-show-dialog]');

if (!dialog.showModal) {
  dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
}

[...showDialogButtons].forEach(showDialogButton =>
  showDialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    dialog.showModal();
  }));

dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
  dialog.close();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<button data-show-dialog class="mdl-button mdl-js-button">
  Обратиться
</button>

<button data-show-dialog class="mdl-button mdl-js-button ">
  Задать вопрос
</button>

<dialog class="mdl-dialog" id="dialog-contact">
  <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
    <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
      Отправить
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="mdl-button mdl-js-ripple-effect close">
      Закрыть
    </button>
  </div>
</dialog>
```